# PHP CodeIgniter class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following classes

```
application\Controllers\Appointments.php

application\controllers\api\v2\AppointmentsV2.php
```

From AppointmentsV2 I want to access Appointments class, I tried many ways not working
I tried almost every thing always not working

```
require (APPPATH.'/Controllers/Appointments.php');
```

The class dose not use name scpace

```
class AppointmentsV2 extends EA_Controller {}
class Appointments extends EA_Controller {}
class EA_Controller extends CI_Controller {)
```

Error:

Message: Class 'Appointments' not found

Comment: Check the path `controllers` !== `Controllers`, Check your `$config['base_url']` is set correctly, Print `APPPATH` ad check what it contains

Comment: If you have created classes that do not follow the PSR-4 naming convention then you'll need to set special autoload rules in `composer.json` file, but I'm sure you'll get clashes if you put them together with the complying classes. Is there a solid reason to skip this naming convention? Is it possible to at least put these classes in an entirely different directory tree?